# Cloudformation template for AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to spin up an RDS stack via a Cloudformation template. I would like to enable Enhanced Monitoring on my DB instances. In order to do that, the `MonitoringRoleArn` property must be specified on the resource.

As I understand it, this ARN should point to an IAM Service Role that has been given the `AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole` policy, as described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html

I would ideally like to also create that role via Cloudformation. For the life of me, however, I can not find an example of how to do this in a Cloudformation template. And it turns out that the Cloudformer tool does not analyze IAM resources.

Has anyone done this? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in YAML:

```
Role:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  Properties:
    ManagedPolicyArns:
    - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole'
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2008-10-17'
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: 'monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com'
        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

You then need to reference the role in your RDS instance's MonitoringRoleArn property like this:

```
!GetAtt ["Role", "Arn"]
```

If you need the example in JSON let me know.

Comment: I had to add a second allow statement for `monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com` per  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html which avoids the error `IAM role ARN value is invalid or does not include the required permissions for: ENHANCED_MONITORING`

Comment: maybe because you enabled enhanced monitoring?

Comment: The trusted entity must be `monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Can confirm please update to `Service: 'monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com'`

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly using monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com

Comment: AWS's "Protecting against the confused deputy problem" suggests using a StringLike condition with the db's ARN as the value on AssumeRolePolicyDocument. That can create a circular dependency - db references the role as the value for the MonitoringRoleArn property, while the role references the db to retrieve its ARN. You can guess the ARN, but maybe only if you specify DBInstanceIdentifier, but then "you can't perform updates that require replacement of this resource." See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.Enabling.html#USER_Monitoring.OS.confused-deputy

Answer (score 8):

Like **avisheks** mentioned, there was a change. 
The example from **hellomichibye** doesn't work anymore. This is my code in YAML (with configurable parameter):

```
Parameters:
  EnableEnhancedMonitoring:
    Description: 'Provide metrics in real time for the operating system (OS) that your DB instance runs on.'
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: false

Conditions:
  HasEnhancedMonitoring: !Equals [ !Ref EnableEnhancedMonitoring, 'true' ]

Resources:
  EnhancedMonitoringRole:
    Condition: HasEnhancedMonitoring
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: ''
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole
      Path: "/"

  DBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      ...
      MonitoringInterval: !If [HasEnhancedMonitoring, 60, 0]
      MonitoringRoleArn: !If [HasEnhancedMonitoring, !GetAtt ['EnhancedMonitoringRole', 'Arn'], !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is little change in the code:

```
    "EMRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole"
            ],
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2008-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RoleName": "rds-monitoring-role"
        }
    }
```

Change: **"Service": "monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"**

Call it as `"MonitoringRoleArn": {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EMRole", "Arn" ] },`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, the above answers are helpful and because of that, I was able to accomplish in **Terraform**. Thinking the below code can be helpful to someone.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "rds-enhanced-monitoring-role" {
  name                = "rds-enhanced-monitoring-role"
  assume_role_policy  = "${file("enhanced-rds-monitoring-policy.json")}"
  description         = "RDS enhanced monitoring role"
  tags = {
      Name            = "rds-enhanced-monitoring-role"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "rds-enhanced-monitoring-role-policy-attachment" {
  policy_arn          = "${data.aws_iam_policy.iam-rds-enhanced-monitoring-access-policy.arn}"
  role                = "${aws_iam_role.rds-enhanced-monitoring-role.name}" 
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "iam-rds-enhanced-monitoring-access-policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole"
}
```

*enhanced-rds-monitoring-policy.json*

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
   {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can enable it :

```
"EnablePerformanceInsights" : Boolean,
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: performance insights and enhanced monitoring are two distinct features - the former to "Assess the load on your database" and the latter to "Look at metrics in real time for the operating system"; see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html#MonitoringOverview.tools