# How to export PostgreSQL logs of a RDS instance in CloudFormation to CloudWatch?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attempting to get the postgreSQL logs from an RDS instance that is using version 10.6, which is set up in a cloudformation template. When I run it through out system I'm getting the error message

> You cannot use the log types 'Postgresql' with engine version postgres 10.6. For supported log types, see the documentation.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-enablecloudwatchlogsexports) seems pretty straight forward in what it asks for. A list of strings to for the parameters, and [postgreSQL supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html#USER_LogAccess.PostgreSQL.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs) both *Postgresql log* and *Upgrade log*. I know this to be true as I am able to export these logs though the AWS console. The documentation doesn't mention what strings are expected. So I've tried 'postgres', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_log', and so on but nothing is catching. I'm sure I must be missing something important but I can't find it, and [the only example I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294802/cloudformation-template-for-amazonrdsenhancedmonitoringrole) on the internet ahsn't been able to enlighten me.

```
   RDSInstance:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
        DependsOn: RDSMonitoringRole
        Properties:
            ****
            EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
                - Postgresql
            MonitoringInterval: 60
            MonitoringRoleArn: !GetAtt ["RDSMonitoringRole", "Arn"]
            ****

    RDSMonitoringRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyArns:
                - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonRDSEnhancedMonitoringRole
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2008-10-17'
                Statement:
                    -
                        Effect: Allow
                        Principal:
                            Service: 'monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com'
                        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs are quiet confusing, but if you read carefully you can see that
under [Publishing PostgreSQL Logs to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html#USER_LogAccess.PostgreSQL.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs) it is written that:

> You can publish the following log types to CloudWatch Logs for RDS for
> PostgreSQL:
>
> Postgresql log
>
> Upgrade log (not available for Aurora PostgreSQL)

When navigating to the AWS CLI examples:

1 ) You can see under: **Example Modify an instance to publish logs to CloudWatch Logs**:

> The key for this object is `EnableLogTypes`, and its value is an array
> of strings with any combination of `postgresql` and `upgrade`.

2 ) Further on under: **Example Create an instance to publish logs to CloudWatch Logs**:

> The strings can be any combination of `postgresql` and `upgrade`.

---

For those who use Aurora PostgreSQL - taken from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.CloudWatch.html):

> Be aware of the following: Aurora PostgreSQL supports publishing logs
> to CloudWatch Logs for versions 9.6.12 and above and versions 10.7 and
> above. 
> From Aurora PostgreSQL, only postgresql logs can be published.
> Publishing upgrade logs isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, I also struggled with this, the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html#USER_LogAccess.PostgreSQL.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs) weren't really helpful either.

Until I opened the "AWS CLI" section:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
    --cloudwatch-logs-export-configuration '{"EnableLogTypes":["postgresql", "upgrade"]}'
```

And those values worked for me.

I see that you mentioned you already tried them, so then maybe you ran into the version limitation?

> Publishing log files to CloudWatch Logs is only supported for PostgreSQL versions 9.6.6 and above and 10.4 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late but might help someone else:

According to docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-enablecloudwatchlogsexports

```
 RDSInstance:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
        DependsOn: RDSMonitoringRole
        Properties:
            ****
            EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
                - postgresql
            MonitoringInterval: 60
            MonitoringRoleArn: !GetAtt ["RDSMonitoringRole", "Arn"]
            ****
```

Answer (score 0):

The allowed values of `EnableCloudwatchLogsExports` are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html). As of this writing, they are:

- Amazon Aurora: Not applicable. CloudWatch Logs exports are managed by the DB cluster.
- RDS Custom: Not applicable.
- MariaDB: Possible values are `audit`, `error`, `general`, and `slowquery`.
- Microsoft SQL Server: Possible values are `agent` and `error`.
- MySQL: Possible values are `audit`, `error`, `general`, and `slowquery`.
- Oracle: Possible values are `alert`, `audit`, `listener`, `trace`, and `oemagent`.
- PostgreSQL: Possible values are `postgresql` and `upgrade`.